# Jade to HTML Undefined field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, pug

I am trying to convert some code I found for an example only from Jade to HTML. Everything is working fine but I keep getting this error from the server "TypeError: Cannot read property 'under' of undefined". I understand that the value posted is undefined which is why the error is being caused. Is there something wring with my HTML code on why the value isnt being submitted properly?

```
JS...

    var primesApp = angular.module('test', []);

    primesApp.controller('testing', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.results = [];
    $scope.submit = function(target) {
      console.log($scope.under) // undefined
      $http.post('/' + 'grabber', {under:$scope.under})
             .then(function(docs)  {
            $scope.results = docs.data.results;
          });
      };
    });



Jade...
form(ng-submit="submit('" + target + "')")
    label(for="under")  
    input(ng-model="under")
    button(type="submit") Submit

HTML...
<form ng-submit="submit('grabber')">
      <input type="text" id="fruit" name="under" ng-model="under" value="apples"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You sure this is not angular complaining there is no "under"?

Comment: when i logged the value of under, it was undefined, so its actually being posted but with the value as undefined...

Comment: @lonewarrior556 i added the JS code to show where i get undefined...

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing an  `ng-init="under='apples'"` in the form tag, 
`value=` doesn't work well with ng-model

or you can init it inside your controller `$scope.under = "apples";`

Comment: It worked, and it print out in the console the value, but I think u were right... When the value goes to the server it now gives the same error.

Comment: I would also remove the <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> and just add a div that looks like a button with an ng-click="submit('grabber')" Other wise you might need to prevent default on the form which can submit independently of your angular ajax call. Maybe. I never used ng-submit.